# Python Enum class membership

Tags: python, enums

When using the [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) class introduced in Python 3 [programmatically](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) , how should a programmer check for Enum membership of a given integer?

Obviously, you could just [ask for forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp) but is there a membership check function that I have otherwise missed? Put more explicitly, I would like to take an integer value and check to see if its value corresponds to a valid enumeration.

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 2
```

Output:

```
In [13]: TestEnum(0)
Out[13]: <TestEnum.a: 0>

In [14]: TestEnum(4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-09c663e9e214> in <module>()
----> 1 TestEnum(4)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py in __call__(cls, value, names, module, qualname, type, start)
    239         """
    240         if names is None:  # simple value lookup
--> 241             return cls.__new__(cls, value)
    242         # otherwise, functional API: we're creating a new Enum type
    243         return cls._create_(value, names, module=module, qualname=qualname, type=type, start=start)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py in __new__(cls, value)
    474                 if member._value_ == value:
    475                     return member
--> 476         raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
    477
    478     def __repr__(self):

ValueError: 4 is not a valid TestEnum
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can try `4 in TestEnum.__members__.values()`, as long as `TestEnum` derives from `enum.IntEnum`.

Comment: @farsil, put your comment as an answer and I'll mark it answered if there is no subsequent prettier ways

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enum does have a [`__contains__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/enum.py#L295) method, but it checks for member names rather than member values:

```
def __contains__(cls, member):
    return isinstance(member, cls) and member._name_ in cls._member_map_
```

Internally(in CPython) they do have a private attribute that maps values to names(will only work for hashable values though):

```
>>> 2 in TestEnum._value2member_map_
True
>>> 3 in TestEnum._value2member_map_
False
```

But it's not a good idea to rely on private attributes as they can be changed anytime, hence you can add your own method that loops over `__members__.values()`:

```
>>> class TestEnum(Enum):
...     a = 0
...     b = 1
...     c = 2
...
...     @classmethod
...     def check_value_exists(cls, value):
...         return value in (val.value for val in cls.__members__.values())
...

>>>
>>> TestEnum.check_value_exists(2)
True
>>> TestEnum.check_value_exists(3)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer nicely tells you about `__contains__` which you can use with `in` for keys; but you can also simply cast the Enum to a set and check values provided you inherit from right data type **(don't forget to subclass from int or str depending on your values!)**:

```
In [29]: from enum import Enum
    ...: 
    ...: class TestEnum(int, Enum):  # See int here!
    ...:     a = 0
    ...:     b = 1
    ...:     c = 2
    ...: 

In [30]: 0 in set(TestEnum)
Out[30]: True

In [31]: TestEnum.a in TestEnum
Out[31]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    a = 3
    b = 2
    c = 1


print(TestEnum.b.name,TestEnum.b.value)
```

Or

```
print(TestEnum(2).name,TestEnum(2).value)
```

Output:

b 2

Answer (score 0):

```py
    @classmethod
    def valueList(cls)->list:
        '''
        get my list of values
        
        Return:
            list: the list of values
        '''
        valueList=list(map(lambda c: c.value, cls))
        return valueList
 
    @classmethod
    def isValid(cls,value)->bool:
        '''
        check whether the given value is valid
        
        Args:
            value: the value to check
        
        Return:
            bool: True if the value is a valid value of this enum
        '''
        valueList=cls.valueList()
        return value in valueList
```